# Add text/data along with special characters as a parameter to api(url) in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to Obj-c. I am adding parameter like text (the text may have special characters also)to url. But the url is showing nil, it's not taking value from string.

For example:

```
NSString*strUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hi how@!#$%^^&*()_=+   r u <>,./ where r u"];

NSString *strMainUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com/API/index.php action=listIt&data=%@",strUrl];

NSString *encodeStr = [string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:encodeStr];

NSLog(@" url is =%@",url);
```

But the url is showing nil value. It's not taking "encodeStr" value. How can I solve this problem.Please help me.

I tried with..

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
```

and also

`strEncode=[strEncode stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`

Comment: Please also note that as the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) outlines, you'll want to upvote and accept the correct answer on your posts, otherwise users will be more hesitant to help you in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified example from [here](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// In case you're unfamiliar, this is a category, which allows us to add methods
// to an existing class, even if we didn't create it. It's a nice alternative
// to subclassing.
//
// In this case, we're extending NSString
@interface NSString (URLEncoding)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
@end

@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
               (CFStringRef)self,
               NULL,
               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
               CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        NSString *raw = @"hi how@!#$%^^&*()_=+   r u <>,./ where r u";

            // note also, that your string omits the '?' in the URL
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com/API/index.php?action=listIt&data=%@",
                    [raw urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSURL *finalUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

        NSLog(@"%@", finalUrl);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
http://google.com/API/index.php?action=listIt&data=hi%20how%40%21%23%24%25%5E%5E%26%2A%28%29_%3D%2B%20%20%20r%20u%20%3C%3E%2C.%2F%20where%20r%20u
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, still the url is showing nil. It is taking even the text has spaces but it is not returning which I sent before. Ex: I am sending text like hi how r u. It is returning hi2ou.

Comment: Made my day. Old answer but still works like a charm. I was facing an issue while sharing text containing special characters with WhatsApp using canOpenURL: method. It was skipping most of the special characters. But this answer solved my issue. Thanks Josh.